# Pathfinding: broadest path

Tags: graph, networkx

I have a networkx graph in which a cost has been assigned to each edge, and I want to compute the path from source to target nodes that represents broadest bottleneck instead of shortest path. So, highest edge cost should be minimized instead of the sum of individual edge costs. What algorithm should I use?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you mean.  I think you are looking for the following:  Among all paths from the source to the target nodes, find that path whose maximum value is as small as possible.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Joel yes, that's what I mean.